# Проблема с metamask. Преобразование числа в wei

Tags: javascript

Всем доброго времени суток. В официальной документации есть пример:

```
    sendEthButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
      ethereum
        .request({
          method: 'eth_sendTransaction',
          params: [
            {
              from: accounts[0],
              to: '0x2f318C334780961FB129D2a6c30D0763d9a5C970',
              value: '0x29a2241af62c0000',
              gasPrice: '0x09184e72a000',
              gas: '0x2710',
            },
          ],
        })
        .then((txHash) => console.log(txHash))
        .catch((error) => console.error);
    });
```

У меня возникла проблема с  `value: '0x29a2241af62c0000',`
Как мне например из числа 0.01 получить подобное значение?

Так же в документации сказано следующее:

```
Шестнадцатеричное значение национальной валюты сети для отправки. В основной сети Ethereum это эфир. (открывается в новом окне), который обозначен в wei , что означает 1e-18эфир.

Обратите внимание, что эти числа, часто используемые в Ethereum, имеют гораздо более высокую точность, чем собственные числа JavaScript, и могут вызвать непредсказуемое поведение, если его не ожидать. По этой причине мы настоятельно рекомендуем использовать BN.js. (открывается в новом окне)при манипулировании значениями, предназначенными для блокчейна.
```

Но это не особо помогает. Я пробовал сделать таким образом value: `web3.toWei('0.01','ether'),`

Результат возвращается в подобном виде `10000000000`

Comment: (0.01).toString(16)

Comment: number must be in wei.
Не подходит

Answer (score 0):

[image: консоль]

Добился такого результата с помощью:

```
var costBigNumber = ethers.utils.parseEther('0.01');
        console.log(costBigNumber);
```

Каким образом я могу отобразить на странице значение _hex??

Comment: для получения hex вида используй метод [`.toHexString`](https://docs.ethers.io/v4/api-utils.html#big-numbers)

Answer (score 0):

Только что сталкивался с этим. Спасибо за ответ на свой же вопрос! Дополню его своим ответом :)
Для того, чтобы вывести _hex необходимо дописать совсем немного:

```
    console.log(costBigNumber._hex);
```

Теперь будет вывод как надо! Всем удачи и кода без багов!

Comment: не надо использовать приватные поля для доступа к информации.